# How to use set_trace after hitting ctrl-c during a test using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, exception, pdb

When I'm running some tests, situations come up where there will be unpredictable failures (so I can't put a set_trace in that part of the code without having to rerun the entire test).  I want to be able to use set_trace right away by hitting ctrl-c.  Since this is just an uncaught KeyboardInterrupt exception, I use excepthook to catch it.  A very simplified version of what I'm doing is as follows:

```
#File TestMethods.py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from traceback import format_exception
import sys
from pdb import set_trace

class Methods():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        sys.excepthook = self.excepthook

        self.driver = webdriver.Ie()
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def excepthook(self):
        set_trace()
        self.driver.close()


#File Test1.py
from TestMethods import Methods

test = Methods("google.com")

test.method1()
test.method2()
...
```

Here, I run Test1.py.  Let's say at method30 I see something go wrong that I'd like to figure out right then and there.  I want to hit ctrl-c or something that will take me to the excepthook and allow me to use set_trace.  This actually works for most uncaught exception- it takes me to the method and set_trace activates.  However, when hitting ctrl-c, selenium loses connection, saying:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

It still makes it to the excepthook method and opens set_trace, but without a connection to the browser.  Therefore, I can't actually do anything worthwhile; instead, I have to find that point in the code and call set_trace from there, and, of course, start the test over.  Is there a way for me to to call set_trace mid-test via some sort of interrupt?  Also, I'm pretty much required to run it on IE, but eventually I will be able to use Firefox or Chrome.

What I'm using:

```
Selenium 2.44.0
python 2.7.6 32-bit
Windows 7
IE11
IEDriverServer 32-bit
```